# How to store multiple informations from one table in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently learning mysql. I have a table "person" and another table "exams".
Every exam has a primary key "exam_id" and every "person" has a primary key "person_id".
Every "person" can participate at several "exams", how can I store the information, which "person" participate at which "exam" (but not in a json/array). I can't figure it out.

Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Comment: I guess you need a table with person_to_exam(person_id,exam_id) with one row per "participation"

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work for me :) @Necklondon